# Error reading environment variable in node js script on raspberry pi

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

I’m new to programming on a pi and raspbian. I’m working on a small project written in node js using this package ([node-ig-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ig-api)) which I started on my windows 10 pc and now transferring to run permanently on my raspberry pi 1 (armV6). Managed to install raspbian and node js onto the pi and can run my node js script fine after I set the environment variables required for the program. The next step was to get the script running on boot up and permanently. Tried setting up a service based on this post [daemonizing node js](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=193107), my script looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=IG Automated Trader

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node /home/pi/igAutomatedTrader.js
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
#User=nobody
#Group=nobody
#Environment=PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
Environment=NODE_ENV=production


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I put the service script in the folder:

```
/etc/systemd/system
```

I then set the environment variables eg:

```
export IG_API_KEY=<api key>
```

I can then use the printenv command to see them all listed. I then use the commands to run the servce:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload 
sudo systemctl start igAutomatedTrader
journalctl -u igAutomatedTrader
```

I can see the service starting and them stopping and get the following error:

Error: "value" required in setHeader("X-IG-API-KEY", value)

I've traced the section of code in the ig node package where this value gets set:

```
let headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Accept': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'X-IG-API-KEY': process.env.IG_API_KEY
};
```

I can't work out why the script works when manually started but not when running as a service. Guessing it's to do with either a path or permissions issue but search through stack overflow and the raspberry pi forums but can't find a solution, most likely due to my lack of knowledge on the raspbian OS. Worth noting I've also tried getting pm2 to run the script but get the same error.

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to add `Environment="IG_API_KEY=<api key>"` to the `.service` file. Refer here on how to set environment variables for services: https://serverfault.com/a/413408/411065

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked! I knew it would be something simple.

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because the `IG_API_KEY` environment variable is not defined when you run your nodejs script as a service.

To define the environment variable add `Environment="IG_API_KEY=<api key>"` to the service file.

If you have more environment variables you can create an environment config and specify the path in the `.service` file by adding `EnvironmentFile=<pathToEnvironmentFile>`